# Intellij Idea to use maven submodules from repo/jar instead source (to workaround Scala bug)

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

My maven layout is similar to:

```
Parent
  - ChildJ
  - ChildS
```

`ChildJ` contains Java code (code generated via the Google Protobuf Java compiler)
`ChildS` contains Scala code

When using pure maven, I install ChildJ to the repository, and then ChildS compiles just fine.

When using idea and telling to compile module `ChildS`, it seems to gather the dependencies itself and passes them to the Scala compiler. Normally this should be ok, but since a subtle Java/Scala cooperation issue, the compiler bails out.

So, can I tell IntelliJ to use ChildJ either from the repository, or compile it separately using javac and pass in the class files/jar as dependency?

*Note: Might be related to [IntelliJ IDEA: Maven, project compilation and deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104534/intellij-idea-maven-project-compilation-and-deployment)*